# How do I find proportions correct in a tidydata format?

Tags: r, math, multiple-columns, percentage, tidy

Currently I have a data file in a tidydata format, where there are multiple subjects with individual answers. So it's like this

> ```
> ID |Button-Pressed | Correct_Answer
>
> 1  A  B
> 1  A  B
> 1  A  B 
> 1  B  A  
> 1  B  A  
> 2  A  B  
> 2  A  A
> ```

So what I'd like to do is to find the proportions correct for each ID. I want to somehow find if the value in the 2nd column and the 3rd column are corresponding (the actual values are different, with one column being one of two digits, and the other being one of two words)

So how would I come up with something that would allow me to formulate a table where each participant's proportions correct is listed in a column right next to it? Is there some kind of existing function that'd help me?

Comment: http://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html#summarise-funs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a grouped summarise, though a few things make it a little trickier to immediately spot. First, R is vectorised in most things, so when I do `pressed == correct` this gives a length 7 logical vector. Then, `mean` automatically converts `TRUE` to `1` and `FALSE` to `0`, so the mean is actually just the proportion correct.

EDIT: included an example of using `recode`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
tbl <- tibble(
  id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
  pressed = c("78", "78", "78", "83", "83", "78", "78"),
  correct = c("different", "different", "different", "same", "same", "different", "same")
)

tbl %>%
  mutate(correct = recode(correct, same = "78", different = "83")) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(pct_correct = mean(pressed == correct) * 100)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>      id pct_correct
#>   <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1    1.          0.
#> 2    2.         50.
```

Created on 2018-04-04 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: this would be amazing!! I will figure out to to try it out but I didn't use the values of my actual data in the question. The data I would like to summarize is actually same/different and 78 (for different) and 83(different). how would I go about doing this? should I concert the column with the same/different into 78 and 83 somehow and then just implement what you wrote?

Comment: sorry, I'm still not clear what is actually in your columns. You can look into `recode` to swap out values for direct replacements.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've been trying to convert the data using recode, but have been gettting the error $operator is invalid for atomic objects

Comment: I have one column with the values "same" and "different"', the other column has "78" or "83".

Comment: That is inssanely helpful. Is "correct" suppose to be the column with the same/different values in it? Because I'm trying to use "subjects_data$same_different" instead of correct, and R gives me an error saying $ cannot be used for atomic objects. Should I be using something else instead?

Comment: I get it. For some reason the data table I'm using isn't in the data.frame format.I'm not sure how to convert the column with the same different information to 78 and 83.